# Link to open another dialog window in msi project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

I want to add a hyperlink to my existing dialog window which when clicked by user will open another dialog window in setup project. I am using VS2008. Can anyone please guide me for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio setup projects don't support customization of the existing dialogs, and there is no support for running code from them. If you mean that you have created your own dialog and you're calling from a custom action, all custom actions run at the end, and the dialogs in the MSI are not dialogs you can link to from your own custom action dialogs.